# crystal report not displaying any data of list

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report and trying to practice on it in wpf but the report is not displaying any data.

My code is here:

```
<Window x:Class="CrystalReportDemo.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="900" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
<my:CrystalReportsViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,73,0,0" 
Name="crystalReportsViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstCrystalReport report = new FirstCrystalReport();
        report.Load("DemoCrystalReport.rpt");
        report.SetDataSource((from item in dataContext.tokens
                              select new
                              {
                                  item.nvcraddress,
                                  item.bgIntcontact_no,
                                  item.dtDateOfToken,
                                  item.vcrpan_no,
                                  item.vcrplate_no,
                                  item.token_id,
                                  item.nvcrNameOfCustomer,
                                  item.nvcrMiddleName,
                                  item.nvcrLastName
                              }).ToList());
        crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
}
```

It is not showing any error or anything.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **FirstCrystalReport** , i am unable to understand.
use below code will work.

FirstCrystalReport  report =new FirstCrystalReport();

report.SetDataSource(source);

var vwindow= new viewerWindow();

vwindow.reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report ;

viewerWindow.ShowDialog();